# which variable parts are stored to the stack in this code?

Tags: c, variables, stack, segment

I have this following code and I don't really understand which variable parts in the **test_function** are stored onto the stack segment?

In the book it says "The memory for these variables is in the stack segment", so I presume it is when the variables are actually initialized to a value. Right?

```
void test_function(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
  int flag;       //is it this
  char buffer[10];// and this
                  //or
flag = 31337; //this and
  buffer[0] = 'A'; //this. Or all of it?
}

int main() {
   test_function(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

Comment: what platform? there might not even be a stack.

Comment: Ubuntu 64-bit. I'm pretty sure the stack exists

Comment: Can you explain what your interest is?  The truth is very complicated and depends on a lot of things.  It is hard to know exactly how to answer your question without understanding your motivation for asking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flag`, `buffer`, and `a,b,c,d` will be on the stack (well compiler may just remove all the code and call it dead code since it's unused).

Comment: when they are declared or when they are initialized to a value?

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko When they are declared, storage needs to be there before the values are. On x86 this involves `push` instructions.

Comment: OMG you are right! We need a storage before we can put something in. Thanks! Also another question if you can, what is a context? In the book it says that "the stack is used to store local vars of a function and context during function calls" thanks!

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko The context is the scope of the executing statement. At least when referring to userspace.

Comment: and whats a scope of the executing statement. Sorry if a newb question, I'm sort of new to this.

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko Depending on what function it's being called from. For example `flags` only exists in the context of `test_function` it's possible that you can have a `flags` that exists in global context as well (which can get really confusing). It's even possible to reduce context of things to inside of loop statements and whatnot.

Comment: So basically, the context is the place where the code is written for a function. i.e. test_function {This is the context of that function}

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko Pretty much.

Answer (score 3):

The various C standards do not refer to a stack, what it does talk about is storage duration of which there are three kinds(static, automatic, and allocated). In this case `flag` and `buffer` have automatic storage duration. On the most common systems objects that have automatic storage duration will be allocated on the stack but you can not assume that universally.

The lifetime of automatic objects starts when you enter the scope and ends when you leave the scope in this case your scope would be the entire function `test_function`. So assuming there is a stack then `buffer` and `flag` in most situations that I have seen there will be space allocated on the stack for the objects when you enter the function, this is assuming no optimization of any sort.

Objects with automatic storage duration are not initialized explicitly so you can not determine their initial values you need to assign to them first.

For completeness sake, the various storage durations are covered in the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.2.4` *Storage durations of objects* paragraph *1* says(*emphasis mine*):

> An object has a storage duration that determines its lifetime. There are **three storage
>   durations: static, automatic, and allocated**. Allocated storage is described in 7.20.3.

Lifetime for automatic objects is covered paragraph *5* which says :

> For such an object that does not have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends
>   from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in
>   any way.[...]

Comment: Ok slow down here haha, I don't know much about that yet, what I need to know is: Is the flag and buffer are stored to the stack when they are first declared or when they are initialized to a number/value?

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko: Neither; the space is allocated when the function is first entered (and deallocated when the function exits).  The declarations are only necessary during translation (when the code is being compiled); you won't see any equivalent to the declaration in the compiled code.  Instead, you'll just see instructions that refer to memory locations relative to the stack pointer (assuming you're working on a stack-based platform).

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko Assuming no optimization then space has to be allocated on the stack before you can initialize the objects. Usually this will involve adjustment of the stack pointer.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer :) appreciate you replies. Would have rated your answer but not a rep 15 yet :P

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko No worries, you will get there, happy to help.