# In which memory segment the member variables reside?

Tags: c++, variables, initialization

I am curious to know where the initialized member variable sit in the memory? i.e., css, bss, data segment, heap...

Don't curse me if my question is stupid :)
For example

```
class A
{
    A();
    int m_iVar;
}

A::A(int i)
{
    m_iVar = i;
}

A::A()
{
    m_iVar = 99;
}

main()
{
    A o; // => After compilation, the object o, in which segment does it reside? and especially  where does "m_iVar" reside
    A o1(5); // => After compilation here object o1, in which segment does it reside?and especially where does "m_iVar" reside?

    A *pA = new A; // After compilation, here the memory pointed by pA, I guess it goes to heap, but the variable "m_iVar" where does it reside
}
```

Comment: Nowhere.  The compiler has no reason whatsoever to generate code for this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18834568/951890

Comment: Why don't you check it out yourself? :) It is an interesting exercise to look at the assembly instructions generated by your compiler, and it is then easy to see where everything get stored, as long as you have the debug symbols.

Comment: For plain old vanilla C data is allocated in the program (string literals, etc), in stack (local variables), in heap (data allocated with `new`), or in static (for `static` or `extern` data).  What these are named (eg, "bss") depends on the particular assembler and OS, and is not in the C standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same as any other variable. It's not really specified in the standard, but if you create a local class instance it'll generally reside on the stack, and if you `new` it, it'll reside in the free store. The member variables are just inside the instance as you'd expect. Static class variables will likely reside in one of the data segments.

Non-static instances don't reside anywhere "after compilation", they get created at run time.

Answer (score 1):

Objects of class type are allocated the same as objects of `int` or any other type. Nonstatic class members are allocated inside the containing object.

Local objects by default have "automatic storage" according to the standard, which is implemented by a part of the operating environment commonly called the stack. It doesn't matter whether or how the object is explicitly initialized.

Using `new` allocates memory from the "free store" according to the standard, the implementation of which is also known as the heap.

Static storage, which results from declaration using `static` or `extern` or at namespace scope, is commonly implemented by a data segment such as css, bss, or data, at the compiler's discretion.

An exception exists for `constexpr` objects, which may exist only at compile time with no allocated space whatsoever, if no address for the object is ever used.